# kubectl command to get list of pods running on k8s master node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to get a list of pods that are Running on matser from kubectl?

i have tried this

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --sort-by="{.spec.nodeName}"
```

but this doesnt say whether the node is master or worker

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/):

> A Pod always runs on a **[Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/)**.
>   **A Node is a worker machine in Kubernetes** and may be either a virtual or a physical machine, depending on the cluster. Each Node is managed by the Master

So by definition (even if it runs on the same physical machine than the master), any node is on a "worker machine"

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/5cb72d407cbe2755e581b6de757e0d81760d5b86/a9df9/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/public/images/module_03_nodes.svg]

Only kubectl get node does display a ROLE:

```
vonc@voncvb:~/.kube$ kubectl get node -o wide
NAME           STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                 KERNEL-VERSION
serv0.server   Ready     <none>    18d       v1.9.7    <none>        SUSE CaaS Platform 3.0  docker://x.y.z.z
serv1.server   Ready     <none>    18d       v1.9.7    <none>        SUSE CaaS Platform 3.0   docker://x.y.z.z
serv2.server   Ready     <none>    18d       v1.9.7    <none>        SUSE CaaS Platform 3.0   docker://x.y.z.z
servm.server   Ready     master    18d       v1.9.7    <none>        SUSE CaaS Platform 3.0   docker://x.y.z.z
                         ^^^^^^^
```